# Exchange JavaScript Variables with JSP without inline scripts

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I am trying to get a varible, which is being set within a JSTL Tag inside of an external JavaScript file.

It needs to be seperated files since the CPS (Content Security Police) of the used browsers is not allowing inline scripting, such as `<script> //some coding here within HTML Document </script>`

To me more specific, here are the relevant HTML and JS codes.

```js
var StartPopup = function() {

  var startPopup = {};

  startPopup.initPage = function() {
    Buttons.addClickHandler("Next1", startPopup.makeNextVisible)
  }

  startPopup.setServerVariable = function() {
    alert("This output is working for test reason");

    //Here i want to retreive the bool varible from serversided JSP
    //and set the variable to true and pass it back to JSP

  }

  return startPopup;
}();

Doc.onLoad(StartPopup.initPage);
```

```html
<t:tab visible="true">

  <c:set var="bool" value="${false}"></c:set>
  <!-- bool should be set true within JS -->

  <base:button id="Next1" title="Next" />


</t:tab>

<t:tab visible="${bool}" id="TechDev" title="TabTitle">

  <!-- SOME CODE -->

</t:tab>
```

Whenever the button is clicked, JS is being executed.

So I would like to know basically how communication between serverside JSP and clientside JS is made in this case!

Comment: http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the reply!
Somehow this framework is only working for test purpuse http://localhost:8080/<context>/dwr/test

Any ideas why java methods are not accessible within custom JSP pages?

Comment: No, sorry......